# Create a copy of object, then deleted an element only from the copy, not the original

Tags: javascript

How do I make `obj2` the same as `obj1` but not affected by the deletion?

Currently the `name: 42` entry will be deleted from both objects.

Is it because of hoisting - that is, the deletion occurs before `obj2` is created?

```js
var obj1 = {
 'name': 'John',
 'age': 42,
}

var obj2 = obj1

delete obj1['name']

console.log(obj1)
console.log(obj2)
```

Comment: assigning doesn't make a copy. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object

Comment: Use `Object.assign` to copy, then do whatever you need.

Comment: `var obj2 = {...obj1};`

Comment: If you simply assign an object to a variable JavaScript will copy it by `reference`. It means that both variables are pointing to the same object. You really need to create a new object with the same properties as your target object. Possible duplicate [How do I correctly clone a JavaScript Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object)

Comment: @JonasWilms it won't work with some objects like window.

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/3082296)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **spread** operator of **ES6** as:

```
let obj2 = {...obj1};
```

Read more about spread operator [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

**What's wrong in your code?**

Actually, when you are assigning the `obj1` to `obj2` the reference of `obj1` and `obj2` will become the same i.e., both will share the same memory location address.

Answer (score 4):

Please use the following

```
var obj2 = Object.assign({}, obj1)
```

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Please note that this is not the deep copy or a copy of an object with all the possible properties (it is explicitely stated in the doc attached above)

Comment: And for the complicated object. We can use `_.cloneDeep(obj)` from `lodash` or using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))` to clone a new object.